# How can I change a label to a button in Xcode

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a play/ pause label in a timer app which starts and stops a timer (shown in the code below)

```
    Label("",systemImage: "\(isActive ? "pause.fill" : "play.fill" )")
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
        .font(.title)
        .onTapGesture(perform: {isActive.toggle()})
```

How can this be turned into a button that has "START" and "STOP" text that toggles? `isActive`

Sorry if this is a basic question, this is the first time I'm building an app :)

Comment: What about `Button { isActive.toggle() } label: { isActive ? "STOP" : "START }`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got what you mean, but you can toggle the text similar to how you have toggled the `systemImage:`.

```
Label(isActive ? "START" : "STOP",systemImage: "\(isActive ? "pause.fill" : "play.fill" )")
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
        .font(.title)
        .onTapGesture(perform: {isActive.toggle()})
```

or if you want to convert the whole thing into a button, you can get that done by encapsulating the label with a button.

```
Button {
    print("Tapped")
} label: {
    Label("",systemImage: something)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like instead of  `Label` you're looking for a `Button`.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var play: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            play.toggle()
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text(play ? "START" : "STOP")
                Image(systemName: play ? "play.fill" : "pause.fill")
            }
        }
    }
}
```